# CSS margins in Opera

Tags: css, opera, css-selectors

I am working on [this site](http://healinghands.vtable.us/) and I am having a problem with my upper double quotes located in the widget area, green container. In all the browsers looks good (even in IE7 and IE8) but in Opera something is going on with the margin or padding and as a result it's out of place. Can somebody help me understanding this please!

Comment: I would fix your HTML before trying to debug CSS issues: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fhealinghands.vtable.us%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0 (18 errors) For one thing, the string `<?php echo bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>` is leaking into your output somehow... Plus you have duplicate `id`s, missing quotes, a script with `src="[JS library]"`, and other problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd try removing the `margin-top` from `.textwidget #testimonial` (line 1652 in your style) and move it to `.textwidget` class. (Found it in 10 seconds using Opera dragonfly).

Comment: Dragfly is a tool embedded in opera. It activates when you right click an element and choose "check element". Kinda like in Chrome.

Comment: Thank you! it's all fixed now! oh by the way how can I do to make my background image stays in the same position as home page. you can see the homepage here [link] (http://healinghands.vtable.us) and my **concern** in here [link] (http://healinghands.vtable.us/board-of-directors) so what I need is all the pages to have the same feeling as home page but can't figure it out yet! Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you ask a new question please open a new thread so the site remains relevant :)